# Select name of alias of xmlns atribute by xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

**Say I have xml with xmlns:alias attribute:**

I need to select allias name from desired namespace?

```
<exmpletag
    xmlns:x="http://www.someurl.url"
>
<sometags/>
<exmpletag>
```

How do I select `x` from `exmpletag` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing the current context (`.`) is the `exmpletag` element, you should be able to do so like this:

```
local-name(namespace::*[. = 'http://www.someurl.url'])
```

Example usage:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="exmpletag">
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name(namespace::*[. = 'http://www.someurl.url'])"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output when run on your sample XML (after fixing it to be well-formed):

```
x
```

I would provide an xsltcake example, but the site appears to be down right now.